# Pass additional properties to AutoMapper Mappings

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

Is it possible to map objects something like this?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ConstructUsing(s => new Dest(s.first, s.second, s.Context.Options.Items["Id"]));

Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, opt => opt.Items["Id"] = 5);
```

Unfortunately there is no `Contex` property in current lambda of `ConstructUsing` method. Or maybe there is a more elegant way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ForMember(dest => dest.MyProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MySourceProperty));
```

Or try this, if it fits more your needs:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ConvertUsing(MappingFunction);
private Dest MappingFunction(Source source)
{
    // mapping stuff
}
```

You can also use:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().BeforeMap(MappingFunction)
```

Or:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().AfterMap(MappingFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an older version of AutoMapper. The 5.x version includes a context object you can use just like you're trying to do.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
   .ConstructUsing((src, ctxt) => new Dest(src.first, src.second, ctxt.Options.Items["Id"]));
```